# Quest for Minimalistic DTD HTML Language Declaration Standards

Tags: html, standards, multilingual, dtd, meta-tags

In a search towards minimalistic webcoding practices I saw this on the top of my webpages:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="nl" xml:lang="nl">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="language" content="nl"/>
```

A: when should one keep the second line (xmlns) and when can it be removed?

B: my website is multilingual so pages come in variety of languages. I kept the xmlns since I swa you can put in lang= and xml:lang= so thought that might be handy, but I don't use xml I think... just php generated contents etc.  UPDATE  I just got advise to use `<html lang="de">` which will suffice for me. True?

C: when does one need the third line http-equiv? When can it be removed entirely?

D: do browsers recognize/process the fourth line or do they skip it nowadays?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, read up on HTML5 [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) or maybe [here](http://html5demos.com/), and maybe even [here](http://html5boilerplate.com/). HTML5 is the latest HTML spec currently under development by the W3C, and is pretty much awesome.

For your questions:

Q1: See [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320161/html5-html-attributes-xmlns-lang-xmllang) Basically, you won't need the `xmlns` or `xml:lang` attribute.

Q2: Yes, see below.

Q3: You don't need to specify `content-type` anymore, however you should always specify the encoding (see below). In reality, though, you can use either one, so I would just stick with the short version. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/which-one-to-use-meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) for more info.

Q4: That's a difficult question to answer because it really depends on the browser / version. However, it's a moot point since the `lang` attribute should really be moved into the `html` tag (again, see below).

Below is what I consider the bare minimum a proper web page should include, (sans the comments):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <!-- use whatever language code is appropriate here -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 is universally the best encoding option -->
    <title>My Cool Website</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Moses +1 very clear and clean answer! much appreciated.